# Powershell Getting Log outputs from "Remove-Item"

Tags: powershell, logging

I'm pretty new to powershell.
I need to learn it though.
I started with a simple script that deletes certain file extensions in different paths, if they are older than 10 days.

```
    $DeleteDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)
    $path1 = "\\path1\*.tibx*"
    $path2 = "\\path2\*Backup Set*"
    $path3 = "\\path3\*.tibx*"
    
    Get-ChildItem $path1 | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt "$DeleteDate"} | Remove-Item
    Get-ChildItem $path2 -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt "$DeleteDate"} | Remove-Item  
    Get-ChildItem $path3 | Where {_.LastWriteTime -lt "$DeleteDate"} | Remove-Item
```

This works so far. Now what I would also need is, that it is logging, what and when it was deleted.
The only problem about this is, that Remove-Item doesnt seem to have output. Not even with "verbose".

I thought about putting the Items in an array, then write the array before and after the delete in a log file.
But this seems kinda complex for a task this simple.
Do you have any Ideas that could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Insert `ForEach-Object` in the pipeline(s) just before `Remove-Item`, then log it there:

```
Get-ChildItem $path1 | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt "$DeleteDate"} | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Verbose "Deleting '$($_.FullName)' at [$(Get-Date -Format o)]"
  $_
} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Well. I tested a bit with this. It still deletes the file as it should.

The only output I get is the code though

```

PS C:\Users\justi>>> 
$DeleteDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)


$pathSV001 = "C:\Users\justi\Downloads\album_1f014i8e4.gif"



Get-ChildItem $pathSV001 | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt "$DeleteDate"} | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Verbose "Deleting '$($_.FullName)' at [$(Get-Date -Format o)]"
  $_
} | Remove-Item


PS C:\Users\justi>>>

```

Comment: You probably dont have verbose printing enabled, this can be enabled by setting $VerbosePreference = 'Continue' prior to running the code